# How to transform a matrix into lower-triangular form using permutation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutation-matrices

Given a real n$\times$n matrix $A$, all diagonal entries are $0$, there are at most $(n-1)$ non-zero entries in $A$, and if $A(i,j)$ is non-zero, $A(j, i)$ is $0$. For example, a matrix $A$ is

\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
4 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}

I want to find a permutation matrix $T$, such that $TAT^T$ is a strictly lower triangular matrix. If possible, I want the non-zero entries which are already located at the strictly lower triangular in matrix $A$ keep staying at their original row and column at much as possible.

For example, I want to move '2' in the above matrix $A$ into a strictly-lower triangular location, at the same time, I want to keep '$4, 1, 3$' at their original locations as much as possible.

What is the general algorithm to find such a permutation matrix $T$? Thank you all very much.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not a $T_1MT_2^T$ with possibly different $T_1$ or $T_2$ ? or plainly $MT^T$ (a parent of the so-called QR decomposition) ?

Comment: Thank you first. I need a similarity transformation of $A$ (your $M$) with permutation matrix $T$. So your $T_1$ and $T_2$ should be the same in my application, and $T$ is a permutation matrix. The only thing I know is that for a similarity transformation with permutation matrix, $TA$ changes the row orders, and $TAT^T$ changes the column orders. But I don't know a general algorithm or strategy to fulfill the goal in my question.

Comment: See [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1842).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm not an expert in this topic, I think the provided information is indeed the answer for people like me who would like to dive deeper. A directly related paper can be referred to (https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01189621/document)